Time-domain channel estimation using identical guard interval vectors
Assuming we have the received signal
$y = h * x $
where $*$ is circular convolution, $x$ is the transmitted signal, $y$ is the received signal and $h$ is frequency selective channel. The signal $x$ is composed of different symbols each includes the data and CP guard interval. For example, $x = [s_{cp} \ \  s_1 \ \   s_{cp} \ \ s_2 \ \ s_{cp} \ \ s_3 ...] $ so the $s_{cp}$ is representing the cp guard interval longer than the channel delay, and assuming $x_{cp}$ known and constant over the whole frame, $s_1, s_2, s_3, ....$ are the data vectors which are not know. Assuming the channel is constant during each symbol duration, my concern is can the channel be estimated using the CP guard interval inserted before and after the symbol? For example using cross correlation or any other operation.
NP: When considering the convolution operation, the $s_{cp}$ is also affected by the interference with the previous data vector due to the frequency-selective channel, so according to my knowledge  it cannot be directly used for estimating the channel.
